# How can I avoid player see through the avatar?

Tags: unity, 3d, virtual-reality

I'm creating a SteamVR/HTC Vive game with Unity3D. I have a rigged avatar performing animations. Currently, if the player goes forward, it will see the moving eye balls and others inside the head. Since it's a small space, I can't allow him to step back to avoid the see-through caused by the collision.

What are other options to avoid it?

I'm thinking about setting up two colliders, one on the animated model and the other on the head of the player, so it can trigger a 360 dark screen to warn the player. How should I create the dark screen for the warning?

Comment: Why do you even render the eyeballs and the head? The player won't be able to see that

Comment: @Bálint No, not he eyeballs and the head of the player. I mean the eyeballs and the head of other characters that the player see.